# Something like a round \widehat

Tags: accents

How can I write something like this:

[image: arrows].

Arrows are the easy part, but I think I need something like `\widehat{}` for brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `\wideparen` from `mathabx`

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{mathabx}

\begin{document}

$\wideparen{\wideparen{\uparrow}\wideparen{\downarrow}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Usual caveat: `mathabx` changes the shape of almost all symbols.